# How to add case insensitive to these regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I need advice on how to add case insensitive (?i) to these strings of regular expressions, so I don't have to make double rows with big and small letters.

```
 <RegEx find="(sumlja)(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*" replaceWith="sumnja$2"/>
```

I have about 100 of lines like that so far, and there'll sure be more,
and I could really use your help on this matter. I work in C# with this,
and I'm not a coder. Just trying to learn this for things I need to do.

Comment: Like this: `find="(?i)(sumlja)(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*"`. Does it work for you? This will be applied to the whole pattern. To apply it to just the first capture group use: `find="(?i:(sumlja))(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*"`

Comment: so I don't need to add (?i) to word after = in order to change it too?

Comment: If you just add a `(?i)` in the very beginning of a pattern, it is applied to the whole regex. No need to add it for each subsequent "word" in the pattern. Does it answer your question? Does it work for you?

Comment: this solution picks up big letter from word I wanna replace, but as I see it, it doesn't recognize that replaced word should have big letter too. it replaces with word with small letter instead. –

Comment: Could you give more information? Such as the app/program you are using because the line in your question is not from the C# I know about.

Comment: @Jerry I can give you information that program is called [SubtitleEdit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit) but I wrote the code for substituting variants of words by guidelines on regular expressions I got on a forum. Code by itself works fine, and changes words, but I need it to change this variant as well:  `<RegEx find="(Sumlja)(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*" replaceWith="Sumnja$2"/>` so, small first letter for small first letter, and big first letter and when first letter is big, it should stay big. But I don't want to double lines. That's all.

Comment: @sandokan Ok, I'm not good at that stuff... but for your regex, I guess that the simplest way would be to use two replaces, one being `<RegEx find="(?i)(?<=sum)(?-i:l)(?=ja)" replaceWith="n"/>` and the second for the uppercase `l`: `<RegEx find="(?i)(?<=sum)(?-i:L)(?=ja)" replaceWith="N"/>`. Otherwise, you will have to create a function that will replace the uppercase letters with the uppercase version of the replacement letters, something [like this](http://ideone.com/9milXy).

Comment: @Jerry I don't know why you assumed that letters L and N need to be recognized and replaced ??? I never said anything like that. 
I only ask that first letters of each word be recognised.
Like it doesn't matter if word is written sumljam or Sumljam, they would be replaced with their equivalents: sumljam , Sumnjam.
Can this be done without using two replaces? That's what I'm trying to avoid this whole time; double lines for same things.
Also, my file is .XML and it can only look similar to this: http://goo.gl/NwdJPj That is original spanish file with RegEx.

Comment: My version, since I'm not a coder contains over 100+ words, and here is only a tiny part of them: http://pastie.org/private/xmgbkoeync0cts3352rrag
How to incorporate uppercase / lowercase in this?
I asked original question wrong, I guess. it should be case sensitive. :(

Comment: @sandokan I had no idea what you were exactly trying to do. And no, you never said it was only the first letter of the word; I was under the impression that you are writing 1 regex each time, thus make it so that depending on what word it was, you would change the regex. In the example of your question, only one letter was different, so that's why the code looked like that. If you can only change those lines, then you will have to make double lines if the first letter in "find" is different from that in "replace", otherwise you could do something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/vF8rF3/1).

Comment: Note that `(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*` is not really doing anything if you are leaving it like this (not changing anything), hence why I dropped it in the above link.

Comment: @Jerry thank you for all your help & explanations. This mostly solved my problems, since, as you say, there is no other way if letters aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this:

```
 find="(?i)(sumlja)(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*".
```

Case insensitive option will be applied to the whole pattern.

To apply it to just the first capture group use `(?i:PATTERN)`:

```
 find="(?i:(sumlja))(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*"
```

**EDIT**:

If your input string can be in lower or upper case only, you can use the following C# code:

```
var rxPtrn =  new Regex(@"(?i)(sumlja)(m|š|mo|te|ju|li)*");
var str = "SUMLJAM"; // JUST A TEST STRING
var res = rxPtrn.Replace(str, m => (m.Groups[2].Value == m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper() ? "SUMNJA" : "sumnja") + m.Groups[2].Value);
```

It will output `SUMNJAM` when you test it against `sumljam`. The only normal case it does not cover is the Title case, but it is easy to add. Please let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Then, you would not want to use `Ignorecase` option in the first place. It can only be done with the code. Can you use regular C# code?